# XY Diagram/Data Browser for mid-sized CSV files

Tags: microsoft-excel, software-rec, csv, diagrams, data-visualization

I have a set of CSV files with about a 100k records in them. The records need to be visualized in an x-y diagram.

Specifically, I'm looking for:

1. Seamless zooming in and out of the data
2. Navigation on both axis
3. A "trace    mode" where I can trace
   the line with    the cursor and the
   value under the    cursor is
   displayed as text.

Does anyone know a tool capable of this?

I do often need to plot sensor data in charts and am currently using Excel for the purpose. Most of the time, I need line and scatter/xy plots with multiple series.

However, Excel charts are not interactive. I want to be able to easily zoom and pan in the data. Basically a data browser. I am looking for software recommendations for Windows or Mac. Anyone knows a good tool?

I've looked into a couple of Excel macros (always require custom VBA code) and the Grapher.app that ships with OS X (painful to import data, only xy plots).

Answer (score 1):

[Spotfire](http://spotfire.tibco.com/) is an amazing commercial application that can do visualizations of large amounts of data, including scatterplots. Spotfire has a web player and [demo gallery](http://spotfire.tibco.com/demo/default.aspx). It is expensive, but has a free trial.

For a scatterplot example, see the Pilot Hours Comparison tab of the [Airline Incident Analysis demo](http://ondemand.spotfire.com/Public/ViewAnalysis.aspx?file=Public/Airline%20Incident%20Analysis&waid=de47ca0f805e48b4277a2-d2ea).

Comment: It's a bit too heavy I think, but I'll have a look

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sqliteviz](https://lana-k.github.io/sqliteviz/) which I'm the author of. It's an open-source offline-first PWA. It allows creating charts for data from SQLite database or CSV files. Drop your CSV file in sqliteviz and it will be converted into SQLite database. After that, you can get all data with `SELECT * FROM csv_import` query and create a chart. The chart will be an interactive [Plotly](https://plotly.com/javascript/) visualization as you described in your question:

[image]

Visit sqliteviz [documentation](https://github.com/lana-k/sqliteviz/wiki) to discover more details.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to roll your own solution with [Processing](http://processing.org/learning/gettingstarted/) (open source)

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution using Grapher, which comes with MacOS X. You can import a CSV file as a Point-Set via Equation->New Point Set. Works like a charm.